bottomNavigationBar reset state bloc
When switching tabs, reset the state value of the state manager bloc. There is no update of the state when switching to stack. It is the tabs that are being updated.I have been working with flutter recently, strange behavior for me. What could be wrong?
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/bloc/favorites/favorites_cubit.dart';
// import 'package:badges/badges.dart' as badges;
import 'package:flutter_coffee/bloc/home_coffees/home_coffees_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/bloc/notifications/notifications_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/custom_icons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/pages/favorites_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/pages/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/pages/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/pages/notifications_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.white),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF201520),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: const TabBar(
            indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.0),
            ),
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(CustomIcons.home, size: 26)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CustomIcons.cart, size: 26)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CustomIcons.favorites, size: 26)),
              // Tab(child: badges.Badge(
              //   badgeContent: Text('3', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'OpenSans', color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), fontSize: 14.0),),
              //   badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(padding: EdgeInsets.all(6), badgeColor: Color(0xFF355555),),
              //   child: Tab(icon: Icon(BottomTabsIcons.notifications, size: 29)),
              // ),),
              Tab(icon: Icon(CustomIcons.notifications, size: 29)),
            ],
            labelColor: Color(0xFFEFE3C8),
            unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xFF746763),
            dividerHeight: 78,
            dividerColor: Color(0xFF22151F),
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 12),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              // BlocProvider(
              //   create: (_) => HomeCoffeesCubit(),
              //   child: const HomeScreen(),
              // ),
              MultiBlocProvider(
                providers: [
                  BlocProvider(
                    create: (_) => HomeCoffeesCubit(),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider(
                    create: (_) => FavoritesCubit(),
                  ),
                ],
                child: const HomeScreen(),
              ),
              const CartScreen(),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (_) => FavoritesCubit(),
                child: const FavoritesScreen(),
              ),
              BlocProvider(
                create: (_) => NotificationsCubit(),
                child: const NotificationsScreen(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

favorites_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/bloc/favorites/favorites_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_coffee/components/favorite_item.dart';

class FavoritesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FavoritesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocBuilder<FavoritesCubit, List<dynamic>>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                ListView(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 46, right: 16, bottom: 32),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Center(
                            child: Text('Favorites', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Rosarivo', color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), fontSize: 24.0),),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                          Column(
                            children: state.isEmpty ? 
                              [const Text('No favorites', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Rosarivo', color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), fontSize: 14.0),),] : 
                              state.map((favorite) => 
                                FavoriteItem(
                                  name: favorite['name'], 
                                  category: favorite['category'], 
                                  description: favorite['description'], 
                                  milks: favorite['milks'], 
                                  milk: favorite['milk'], 
                                  urlImage: favorite['urlImage'], 
                                  price: favorite['price'], 
                                  rating: favorite['rating'],
                                ),
                              ).toList(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}

favorites_cubit.dart
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class FavoritesCubit extends Cubit<List<dynamic>> {
  FavoritesCubit() : super([]);

  void addFavoriteCoffee(String name, String category, String description, List<dynamic> milks, String milk, String urlImage, int price, double rating) {
    var coffees = state.where((coffee) => coffee['name'] == name).toList();
    if(coffees.isEmpty) {
      emit([...state, {'name': name, 'category': category, 'description': description, 'milks': milks, 'milk': milk, 'urlImage': urlImage, 'price': price, 'rating': rating}]);
    } else {
      emit([...state.where((coffee) => coffee['name'] != name).toList()]);
    }
  }

  void deleteFavoriteItem(String name) {
    emit([...state.where((coffee) => coffee['name'] != name).toList()]);
  }
}

click on the stack:
enter image description here
click on the tab:
enter image description here

can you try creating bloc instance and pass them

@Md. Yeasin Sheikh, i don't quite understand what you mean
